# py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:50961)

Tags: java, python, pyspark

I am trying to read an excel file using spark.
Spark is installed locally on my machine.
But I am getting the **ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it** error.

With this, I am getting **py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:50961)** issue also.
Not sure this is because of JAVA or not.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: "actively refused" means its not set up to accept on that port, check your configs/security, possibly firewall. also check that spark is set to recieve on 127.0.0.1, it might not be

Comment: @Nullman, I added another error which is coming alongwith the connection refusal error. Any comments on that/.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: make sure you start the gateway before you run the python script, it doesn't start the gateway (and double check the port you are connecting to)